# Insert record into a table which has 180 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables which have 180 columns, and I want to insert a record in all tables continuously using a stored procedure in SQL Server.

What is the best optimized way to do this?

Should I simply write an insert query in the stored procedure, or should I use functions for each insert query and after this I call function in my stored procedure?

Comment: As @marc_s said, you cannot insert records into a table using a function, so you should insert them directly on your stored procedure, or if your insert statements are very complex and you want them to be separated, you can define each one on a separated stored procedure (not a function but a stored procedure), and call all those insert stored procedures from your main stored procedure.

Answer (score 1):

Since **functions** in T-SQL **cannot modify** the database state, you cannot use them to insert data into a table. See the [official MS documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) on function - scroll down to the section "Limitations and Restrictions" where it says:

> User-defined functions **cannot** be used to perform actions that **modify** the database state.

Since you already have a stored procedure, you just need to write three separate `INSERT` statements (one for each table) inside that stored procedure to insert your data into the three tables by calling that stored procedure.

Comment: Or he can also write each insert on a separate stored procedure and call all of them from his main stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Does the 3 tables mentioned has the same number of column, as well as same column name?
If this is so, create a generic function with table name as input parameter would be more easy to use and maintain

Comment: A **function** in T-SQL **cannot** modify the database state - so you **cannot** use it to insert data into a table.